# How to add conditional animation in react & tailwind, if the value of use state changes

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, css-animations

Using "React" and "Tailwind-CSS".
I have button . On clicking it a chat-box,  appears. But I want a fade in animation when the chat-box  appear after clicking the button  rather then direct popup. How will I do it?

Code is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ChatButton from "./ChatButton";
import ChatBoxMain from "./chatBox/ChatBoxMain";

function ChatMain() {
  const [isChatOpen, setIsChatOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleChat = () => {
    setIsChatOpen(!isChatOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isChatOpen ? (
        <ChatBoxMain toggleFunction={toggleChat} /> // chat-box should fade in, not directly popup
      ) : (
        <ChatButton toggleFunction={toggleChat} /> // on clicking this button
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChatMain;
```

I want a fade in animation when the chat-box  appear after clicking the button  rather than direct popup. How will I do it?

Answer (score 0):

first make sure to extend the tailwind config file with an animation like this

```
keyframes: {
    fade: {
      '0%,100% ': { opacity: '1' },
      '50%': { opacity: '0' },
    }
  },
  animation: {
    fadeContent: 'fade 1s linear 1',
  },
```

use a useEffect and useRef
first make a ref to the button
and then in the usEffect make a condition if isChatOpen is true add the animation class to the button  it might be something like this

```
     useEffect(() => {
    if (isChatOpen === true) {
      buttonRef.current?.classList.add('animate-fadeContent')
    } 
 }, [isChatOpen ])
```